# Find limits involving integral of ${\sin (nx)\over \sin x}$

Tags: integration, limits

I would like to find the limits 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{\pi\over n}{\sin(nx)\over \sin x}dx$$
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{\pi\over n}{\sin(nx)\over \sin x}xdx$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $x\to x/n$ to obtain

$$\int_0^{\pi/n}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{n\sin(x/n)}\,dx$$

and then use $x/n-\frac16 (x/n)^3\le \sin(x/n)\le x/n$.